# How can I guarantee that the skeleton forms of MissingNo appear?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

MissingNo. seems to take on different forms for different players. I want to try and get the other forms but I don't know how.

How can you get the skeleton forms of MissingNo?

Answer (score 4):

As explained on [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/MissingNo.#Fossil_and_ghost_MissingNo.) it seems the only way to "control" what form MissingNo will have in terms of the Ghost and Fossil forms is to control your name or using the Time Capsule Glitch

#### Kabutops Fossil form

[image: Kabutops fossil sprite]

> - This form appears through the old man glitch if w is the character in the third, fifth, or seventh slot of the player's chosen name.
> - This form can be obtained through the Time Capsule exploit if the traded Pokémon is Pupitar.

#### Aerodactyl Fossil form

[image: Aerodactyl fossil sprite]

> - This form appears through the old man glitch if x is the character in the third, fifth, or seventh slot of the player's chosen name.
> - This form can be obtained through the Time Capsule exploit if the traded Pokémon is Tyranitar.

#### Ghost form

[image: Ghost sprite]

> - This form appears through the old man glitch if y is the character in the third, fifth, or seventh slot of the player's chosen name.
> - This form can be obtained through the Time Capsule exploit if the traded Pokémon is Lugia.

All 3 mention using the Mew Glitch however I suspect the Special stat requirement will be random

The Ghost form also has an extra way to do it

> - this form appears through evolving .PKMNRB or Z ゥY at level 224.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually control it exactly using the Mew glitch as well; the special stats you need are listed on Bulbapedia, to wit,

> MissingNo. (Kabutops Fossil form)  182
>   MissingNo. (Aerodactyl Fossil form)  183
>   MissingNo. (Ghost form)  184

The easiest way to get the specials you want is to use the Ditto variant of the Mew glitch, as outlined on Bulbapedia: https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mew_glitch#Ditto_glitch . If you're planning on getting Missingno. in Yellow, then these three forms are the safest to use to not corrupt the rest of your game too much.